# Adding an ALL Parameter to SSRS report

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have a query that I use for a parameter for some reports in SSRS. I would like to add an Select ALL option to this parameter. Does that mean that I will need to add another query for my list? Is there a better way to go about doing this? If I go this route I think I will need to modify all of my reports.

```
select EmployeeName,
EmployeeID as EmployeeKey
from dimEmployee
where EmployeeID in ('9','3','4','81','115','68','11' )
order by EmployeeName
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I typically do this is to `UNION` a `NULL` record onto the dataset that populates the list of possible values, then

```
select EmployeeName,
EmployeeID as EmployeeKey
from dimEmployee
where EmployeeID in ('9','3','4','81','115','68','11' )
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  ' ALL ',
  NULL
order by EmployeeName
```

Then in your report query, handle the case where EmployeeID is `NULL`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE @EmployeeID IS NULL OR EmployeeID IN (@EmployeeID)
```

So yes, you will need to modify all of your reports.

Comment: What does the NULL UNION do?

Comment: It gives you an additional item in the select list that can represent an "ALL" option.